# setFontColor on input string in app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I read [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), they show the below function as an example

```
function DOUBLE(input) {
  return input * 2;
}
```

I tried something fairly similar

```
function specialFonts(input) {
  return input.setFontColor('#FFC0CB')
}
```

and I get `input.setFontColor is not a function`  when [I run it on a string](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PoD1iFU21NX8n4tJclLH9G6epWw0z_RgIbBUmZ10NB8/edit#gid=0).

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962555/google-spreadsheet-setfontcolor-error-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-setfo), but it wasn't really helpful.

Any idea how to solve this? Ideally I want to have a function that does some formatting to specific pieces of text in a cell and not all the text in a cell i.e., `=concatenate(a1,char(10),specialFonts(a2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setFontColor() is a method of Class Range. not number
or value

[setFontColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69228006/setfontcolor-on-input-string-in-app-scripts)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Cooper. Do you know if there is another method that'd allow me to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: May be try richText

Comment: Thanks Cooper! I actually saw that what I'm trying to achieve [isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58981698/google-script-custom-function-to-return-rich-text), but it is a feature request being tracked by Google. For posterity, please +1 [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145501368) if you run into this issue!